# Как правильно применить blur эффект к узлу со скругленными краями в javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Я делаю графическое приложение, у которого должны быть закругленные края:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Есть Pane. К нему применяется такое эффекты:

```
paneBlur.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(new Color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9), new CornerRadii(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, false), null)));
    BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur(5.0, 5.0, 3);
    paneBlur.setEffect(blur);
```

Проблема в том, что после применения blur эффекта (любого) закругленные края от этого портятся (края становятся прямоугольными). Как сделать чтобы такого не было?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]